# AMP HTML amp-user-notification CSS padding-right

Tags: css, padding, amp-html

trying to setup amp-user-notification but the padding doesn't work. [padding-right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgqX0.png)

```css
  amp-user-notification {
      min-height: 30px;
      font-family: 'Roboto';
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 30px;
      padding: 8px;
      background: #46b6ac;
    }
```

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/user-notification.amp.html

padding: 8px; doenst work for rgiht side. i think cause parent amp-element is display: inline-block;

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine, it is just that the padding adds to the element's size, so the element overflows. You have to either subtract your padding from your width/height, either add `box-sizing:border-box` to said element.

[padding in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

[box-sizing in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)